# Draw object with multi texture and other object with one texture

Tags: c++, opengl, opengl-4

I want draw object rectangle with two texture and triangle with only one texture. I follow this website

[LearnOpenGL.com - Textrues](https://learnopengl.com/Getting-started/Textures)
https://learnopengl.com/code_viewer_gh.php?code=src/1.getting_started/4.2.textures_combined/textures_combined.cpp

With draw triangle I implement like below :

```
Shader ourShaderTriangle("vshader.glsl", "fshader.glsl");
float firstTriangle[] = {
    // positions         // colors          //textcoord
    -1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,  1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,   0.0f,   0.0f,   // bottom right
    -0.5f, 0.5f, 0.0f,  0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,   0.5f,   1.0f,   // bottom left
    -0.1f,  0.0f, 0.0f,  0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,  1.0f,   0.0f     // top 
};//first
unsigned int VBO1, VAO1;
glGenVertexArrays(1, &VAO1);
glGenBuffers(1, &VBO1);

glBindVertexArray(VAO1);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO1);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(firstTriangle), firstTriangle, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
//position
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 8 * sizeof(float), (void*)0);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
//color
glVertexAttribPointer(1, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 8 * sizeof(float), (void*)(3 * sizeof(float)));
glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
//textCoord
glVertexAttribPointer(2, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 8 * sizeof(float), (void*)(6 * sizeof(float)));
glEnableVertexAttribArray(2);
```

Vertex Shader

```
#version 330 core
layout (location = 0) in vec3 aPos;
layout (location = 1) in vec3 aColor;
layout (location = 2) in vec2 aTexCoord;
out vec3 ourColor;
out vec2 TexCoord;
void main()
{
   gl_Position = vec4(aPos, 1.0);
   ourColor = aColor;
   TexCoord = vec2(aTexCoord.x, aTexCoord.y);
}
```

Fragment:

```
#version 330 core
out vec4 FragColor;
in vec3 ourColor;
in vec2 TexCoord;
uniform sampler2D textureTriangle;
void main()
{
   FragColor = texture(textureTriangle, TexCoord);
}
```

Load texture :i use other texture "container2.png".I store it in "texture3"

```
    glGenTextures(1, &texture3);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture3);
// set the texture wrapping parameters
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);   // set texture wrapping to GL_REPEAT (default wrapping method)
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
// set texture filtering parameters
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
// load image, create texture and generate mipmaps
data = stbi_load(FileSystem::getPath("resources/textures/container2.png").c_str(), &width, &height, &nrChannels, 0);
if (data)
{
    // note that the awesomeface.png has transparency and thus an alpha channel, so make sure to tell OpenGL the data type is of GL_RGBA
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, width, height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);
    glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
}
else
{
    std::cout << "Failed to load texture" << std::endl;
}
stbi_image_free(data);
```

In draw  function:

```
  //bind textures on corresponding texture units
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture1);
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture2);

    // render container
    ourShader.use();
    glBindVertexArray(VAO);
    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);

    //
    ourShaderTriangle.use();
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture3);     
    glBindVertexArray(VAO1);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
    //
```

But triangle still using of texture unit 0 (GL_TEXTURE0).Not using texture i want
[image]

I have try to use "glDisable" ,and "glDeleteTextures" but it doesn't work.

Could you help me?

Comment: Where do you tell the fragment shader, by using `glUniform1i(...)`,  about the texture to use (`uniform sampler2D textureTriangle`)?

Comment: `texture3` is bound to texture unit 1, because the current texture unit isn't changed after `glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1);`. If the texture sampler `"textureTriangle"` should be associated to texture unit 1, then you've to assign 1 to the texture sampler uniform, `GLint tex_loc=glGetUniformLocation(program, "textureTriangle");` `glUniform1i(tex_loc, 1);`.  The uniform has to be set after `ourShaderTriangle.use();`.

Comment: Every time you call `glBindTexture` it puts that texture into the current *Active* texture. The last call to `glActiveTexture` changed the *active* texture to `GL_TEXTURE1`. Then you *bound* `texture2` to draw the quad, and then `texture3` for the triangle. The triangle shader is seeing `texture1` bound to `GL_TEXTURE0` and `texture3` bound to `GL_TEXTURE1`. Try adding a call to `glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0)` before binding `texture3`.

Answer (score 1):

OpenGL is a state engine. The current texture unit which is set by [`glActiveTexture`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glActiveTexture.xhtml) is a global state. So all the following calls to `glBindTexture`, bind the texture to texture unit 1.
If you want to bind `texture3` to texture unit 0, then you've to change the texture unit before binding the texture to the texturing target:

```cpp
ourShaderTriangle.use();
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0); // <---
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture3);     
glBindVertexArray(VAO1);
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
```

---

If you want to use a different texture unit then you've to change the binding point for the texture sampler uniform.

This can be done in shader code by [Binding point Layout Qualifier](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Layout_Qualifier_(GLSL)#Binding_points) (For this at least GLSL version 4.20 has to be used). e.g 1 for texture unit 1:

```c
#version 420 core

layout(binding = 1) uniform sampler2D textureTriangle;
```

The alternative is to assign the texture unit (1) to the texture sampler uniform, after the program is installed by [`glUseProgram`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glUseProgram.xhtml):

```cpp
GLuint program = // program "ourShaderTriangle"
GLint texTriLoc = glGetUniformLocation(program, "textureTriangle");
```

```cpp
// ...
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1);
// ...
```

```cpp
ourShaderTriangle.use();
glUniform1i(texTriLoc, 1); // <----
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture3);     
glBindVertexArray(VAO1);
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
```